# What software can replace AppleWorks on a new Mac?

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation

I just purchased a new Mac Mini, replacing an ancient iMac with AppleWorks. I use that software for email, web-browsing, word processing, spreadsheets and an occasional database.

Is there a package like Appleworks?

All I'm seeing is *Pages*, *Numbers*, etc.  What can replace these functions?

Comment: So YOU were the person who used Appleworks...

Comment: Do you look for a replacement of AW in general or for specific functionality? If the latter what exactly do you need?

Comment: Nancy, you could select an answer...

Answer (score 14):

There isn't a perfect fit for a unified Appleworks replacement - but each of the 5 functions is available directly from Apple either pre-installed or on the App Store.

Apple now has the [iWork suite](http://www.apple.com/iwork/), which used to be a single package you can buy, but is now separate apps on the [App Store](http://www.apple.com/mac/app-store). It is made up of [Pages](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/id409201541?mt=12) (word processor), [Keynote](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote/id409183694?mt=12) (presentation software), and [Numbers](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/numbers/id409203825?mt=12) (spreadsheet). If you want a database consider [Bento](http://www.filemaker.com/products/bento/) or [FileMaker Pro](http://www.filemaker.com/products/filemaker-pro/). All five are made by Apple (the databases are made by FileMaker, an Apple subsidiary). Bento equates to Access, and FileMaker equates to MS-SQL (roughly).  Of course the mail app is the fifth item you will use to fully replace Appleworks.

Edit: Bento is no longer an option.  FileMaker ceased production/support of Bento.  There are other options like TapForms at http://www.tapforms.com.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the advice offered by me in September 2012 to a colleague whose daughter wondered about office suites.

---

… If ever she needs to work with Microsoft Office formats, without Microsoft Office on her Mac:

## [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org)

Free of charge. Donations accepted.

## [NeoOffice](http://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/index.php)

If not using Mountain Lion: slightly outdated NeoOffice 3.2.1 for Leopard, Snow Leopard or Lion on an Intel Mac is free of charge: https://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/mirrors.php?file=NeoOffice-3.2.1-Intel.dmg

**Current NeoOffice 3.3.x** for Snow Leopard, Lion or Mountain Lion on an Intel Mac requires a small donation of £6 or more (less than the cost of Microsoft Office).

If you require support from the (few) developers of NeoOffice, it's more costly – "… [£60 … or more within the last year](http://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/contact.php) …". Developer responses in this area are excellent (far better than Microsoft responses to issues with Office) so the cost is not unreasonable, but I shouldn't rush to recommend this level of investment to an everyday user of an office app/suite.

## Comparison

A key difference, until recently:

- NeoOffice can read and write `.docx`
- some versions of OpenOffice.org (in some ways a predecessor to LibreOffice) could read but **not** write `.docx` files.

The current version 3.6.1.2 of LibreOffice can both read and write .docx :-) – I haven't investigated its ability to do so with great fidelity for all uses of that Microsoft format, or other MS formats, but the developers of LibreOffice are generally well regarded.

## Summary

Try LibreOffice, it's free and should do no harm.

To prefer `.docx` as a default for text documents, see screenshots at http://www.wuala.com/grahamperrin/public/2012/09/26/a/?mode=gallery

If LibreOffice isn't good enough, aim for a reduced cost copy of Microsoft Office.

---

Some of what's above related to Snow Leopard, which you'll not find on a new Mac, but I'm quoting the broad advice exactly as given in September.

Additionally:

## [Apache OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org)

Articles such as [LibreOffice vs. OpenOffice, Not Always Simple « Power corrupts in proportion to its disequilibria](http://decentralist.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/libreoffice-vs-openoffice-not-always-simple/) remind us that some use cases may benefit from this Apache Incubator project. In particular, the closing paragraph:

> … I think that OpenOffice might have had a greater focus on MS Office
>   document compatibility, while LibreOffice has focused on advancing
>   features. I’m afraid my employer needs are squared directly over MS
>   Excel compatibility vs. new features.

Comment: Graham,

Thanks for adding the Open Source alternatives (+1).  I just wanted to make sure you know that the "iWork" suit from Apple handles MS docs (you can import and export .docx, etc.)  I don't know if you could convert an Access database to Bento though.  Never had need to try.

Comment: Apparently you can convert Access to Bento:
http://jabakobob.net/mdbviewer/docs/v2/en/pages/migration/convert-access-to-bento.html

Comment: @Everett thanks – your answer is voted up but here, I excluded iWork because apps such as Pages can not *Save* in a format that is broadly compatible with other suites.